# High poly in object mode, low poly in edit mode

Tags: 3d-view

When I apply the subdivision modifier and smoothing, the object does get a ton more faces, but when I go into edit mode, it shows it as if those faces aren't there, and it's bugging the heck out of me.

Wireframe shading:
[image: Wireframe mode]

Edit mode:
[image: Edit mode]

Comment: post a picture of the modifier stack. Sure looks to me like the subdivision surface is not applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highly likely you just did not apply the Subdivision Surface modifier. Simply go to the modifier tab and hit "apply" under the Subdivision Modifier, then all the correct vertices will appear in edit mode.

Comment: Yea.. That was it. Thanks for the obvious thing I missed :P